# Local Worpdress website can not connect to its database

Tags: wordpress, xampp, wp-cli

I am trying to install a Wordpress site on a local server (Ubuntu 16.04 in a docker container).

Xampp is installed and running, and I have created a database and a username with proper rights:

```
mysql -uroot -e "CREATE USER 'localuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'localpassword';";
mysql -uroot -e 'CREATE DATABASE 'localdatabase';';
mysql -uroot -e "GRANT ALL ON localdatabase.* TO 'localuser'@'localhost';";
```

I've also updated my wp-config.php file with the credentials above.

Still, when I try to install wordpress from there (I use wp-cli), I get the message "Error: Error establishing a database connection. This either means that the username and password information in your `wp-config.php` file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database server at `localhost`. This could mean your host’s database server is down."

I've double checked the credentials, and xampp is indeed running, so what should I check next? Could this come from a config file that is missing something?

Answer (score 0):

What hostname are you using in the wp-config? Also did the commands finish succesfully? For creating the db you used apostrophes instead of quotes. You can try the mysql client directly with mysql -u  -p -h  .

Comment: I'm using 'localhost' in wp-config.php. Yes the commands finish successfully. I checked with SHOW DATABASES; and SHOW GRANTS; , my database has been created, my username too and the username has the rights

Comment: Is the mysql in the same container as wordpress? If so you cannot use localhost, you have to use the ip of the musql container.

Comment: yes they are in the same container. You're saying I can not use localhost in this case?

Comment: If they are in the same container you can use localhost. I mistyped before.

Comment: ah ok that's what I thought. I added the -p 4000:80 option for my docker and tried to access in my host's browser http://localhost:4000/phpmyadmin, but got the error "Access forbidden!
New XAMPP security concept: Access to the requested directory is only available from the local network.This setting can be configured in the file "httpd-xampp.conf"." Is this related to my issue or is it only a because I'm accessing phpmyadmin from the host?

Comment: I was able to access phpmyadmin using lynx in the container so this error was related to accessing phpmyadmin from outside the container. So I still have my original problem.

Answer (score 0):

In wp-config.php, use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost for the database hostname.